# How can I manually add a Spring CacheInterceptor using Java Config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cache, spring-config

I'm trying to work out how I can add caching to method calls on a third party Java class. I'm using *Spring Boot* for my application.

I've come up with this class in my attempts to get caching working.

```
package test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheOperation;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheProxyFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheableOperation;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.NameMatchCacheOperationSource;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
        Greeter greeter = context.getBean(Greeter.class);

        System.out.println(new Date() + " : " + greeter.getGreeting("Bob"));
        System.out.println(new Date() + " : " +greeter.getGreeting("Fred"));

        System.out.println(new Date() + " : " +greeter.getGreeting("Bob"));
        System.out.println(new Date() + " : " +greeter.getGreeting("Fred"));

        System.out.println(new Date() + " : " +greeter.getGreeting("Bob"));
        System.out.println(new Date() + " : " +greeter.getGreeting("Fred"));
    }

    @Bean
    public Greeter greeter() {
        final NameMatchCacheOperationSource nameMatchCacheOperationSource = new NameMatchCacheOperationSource();
        Collection<CacheOperation> cacheOperations = new HashSet<CacheOperation>();
        cacheOperations.add(new CacheableOperation.Builder().build());
        nameMatchCacheOperationSource.addCacheMethod("*", cacheOperations);

        CacheProxyFactoryBean cacheProxyFactoryBean = new CacheProxyFactoryBean();
        cacheProxyFactoryBean.setTarget(new MySlowGreeter());
        cacheProxyFactoryBean.setProxyInterfaces(new Class[] {Greeter.class});
        cacheProxyFactoryBean.setCacheOperationSources(nameMatchCacheOperationSource);
        cacheProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return (Greeter) cacheProxyFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    interface Greeter {
        String getGreeting(String name);
    }

    class MySlowGreeter implements Greeter {
        public String getGreeting(String name) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "Hello " + name;
        }
    }
}
```

The hope is that I'd be able create a bean in my *Spring* config that wraps calls to `Greeter.getGreeting(..)` and returns cached results if they exist. However no caching is taking place.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I have more information for you.  But first, I want to address some issues with your code above.

1) The first issue involves your use of the [`o.s.cache.interceptor.CacheProxyFactoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheProxyFactoryBean.html) in the "greeter" `@Bean` definition of your application `@Configuration` class (i.e. "MyApp").

Anytime you use 1 of *Spring's* `FactoryBeans` (e.g. `CacheProxyFactoryBean`) or implement your own, what you return from the `@Bean` method is the `FactoryBean` itself, **not** the product of the `FactoryBean`.  So, instead of `return factoryBean.getObject()`, you would return the `FactoryBean`, like so...

```
@Bean
GreeterFactoryBean greeter() {
  GreeterFactoryBean factoryBean = new GreeterFactoryBean();
  factoryBean.set...
  return factoryBean;
}
```

Here, `GreeterFactoryBean` implements [`o.s.beans.factory.FactoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html).

As *Spring's* [Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean) points out, the *Spring* container knows to return the product of the `FactoryBean` (e.g. a [*Singleton*] `Greeter` instance) and **not** the `FactoryBean` itself, as the "defined" bean in the *Spring* container for this `@Bean` method.  The name of the bean will be the name of the `@Bean` method if not explicitly defined with `@Bean` (e.g. `@Bean("Greeter")`).

If the `FactoryBean` also implements *Spring's* lifecycle callback interfaces (e.g. [`o.s.beans.factory.InitializingBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) or [`o.s.beans.factory.DisposableBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/DisposableBean.html), etc), the *Spring* container will know to invoke those lifecycle callbacks at the "appropriate" time, during the *Spring* container's initialization process.

Therefore, it is unnecessary to invoke either `CacheProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet()` or `CacheProxyFactoryBean.getObject()` inside the "greeter" `@Bean` definition.  Doing so actually violates the *Spring* container's initialization contract, and you could run into premature "initialization" problems, especially if the provided `FactoryBean` implements other *Spring* container interfaces (e.g. `BeanClassLoaderAware`, or `EnvironmentAware`, and so on and so forth).

Be careful!

2) Second, this is less of an issue/problem with your example than something to just be aware of.  You stated in this SO post that you are trying to add "caching" behavior to 3rd party library classes.

The approach you use above is applicable only when you are able to instantiate the 3rd party class (e.g. `Greeter`) in your application yourself.

However, if the 3rd party library or framework instantiates the class on your behalf, as a result of configuring the library/framework (e.g. think JDBC Driver and Hibernate), you lose the ability to introduce caching behavior to this class in your application, unless your resort to [*Load-Time Weaving*](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-aj-ltw) (LTW).  Read the docs for more details.

Alright, onto the **solution**.

I wrote a test to reproduce this problem and to better understand what is happening inside the *Spring Framework*.  You can find my completed test [here](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/ProgrammaticCachingWithSpringIntegrationTests.java).

[`TestConfigurationOne`](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/ProgrammaticCachingWithSpringIntegrationTests.java#L118-L130) is effectively the same approach you employed to 
create caching proxies programmatically, with modifications based on what I discussed above, and also, to address what I think is a **bug** in the core *Spring Framework* (NOTE: I was using *Spring Framework* `5.0.1.RELEASE` in my test).

In order to get your configuration approach with `CacheProxyFactoryBean` to work, I needed to [extend the `CacheProxyFactoryBean` class](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/ProgrammaticCachingWithSpringIntegrationTests.java#L132-L181).  In addition to [extending](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/ProgrammaticCachingWithSpringIntegrationTests.java#L132) the `CacheProxyFactoryBean`, I also needed to [implement](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/ProgrammaticCachingWithSpringIntegrationTests.java#L133) the [`SmartInitializingSingleton` interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/SmartInitializingSingleton.html) and the [`BeanFactoryAware` interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactoryAware.html) for reasons what will become apparent in a moment.  See [9](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/ProgrammaticCachingWithSpringIntegrationTests.java#L132-L181) for the [complete implementation](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/ProgrammaticCachingWithSpringIntegrationTests.java#L132-L181).

Internally, *Spring Framework's* `o.s.cache.interceptor.CacheProxyFactoryBean` is [making use](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.1.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheProxyFactoryBean.java#L46) of a `o.s.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor`.  It also goes onto "initialize" this `CacheInterceptor` instance, [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.1.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheProxyFactoryBean.java#L55) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.1.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheProxyFactoryBean.java#L72).  However, this does **not** complete the initialization since the `CacheInterceptor` also, indirectly, [implements](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.1.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheAspectSupport.java#L80) the `SmartInitializingSingleton` interface, by [extending](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.1.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheInterceptor.java#L44) `CacheAspectSupport`.  If the `SmartInitializingSingleton` implemented [`CacheInterceptor.afterSingletonsInstantiated()` method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.1.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheAspectSupport.java#L184-L203) is never called, then the [`initialized` bit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.1.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheAspectSupport.java#L202) is never tripped, and any cacheable operations [will **not** be cached](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.1.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheAspectSupport.java#L310), resulting in the [cacheable operation being invoked every single time](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.1.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheAspectSupport.java#L322) (thus, ignoring any introduced caching behavior).

This is the exact reason why I extended the `CacheProxyFactoryBean` in my test class, to [capture](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/ProgrammaticCachingWithSpringIntegrationTests.java#L163-L171) the "mainInterceptor" (i.e. the `CacheInterceptor`) and then call the [`afterSingletonsInstantiated()` method](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/ProgrammaticCachingWithSpringIntegrationTests.java#L156) at the appropriate moment during the *Spring* container's initialization phase, which is why my `SmartCacheProxyFactoryBean` extension implements `SmartInitializingSingleton`, to delegate to the `CacheInterceptor.afterSingletonsInstantiated()` method.

Additionally, the `CacheInterceptor` is `BeanFactoryAware` and [requires](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.1.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheAspectSupport.java#L186-L190) the *Spring* `BeanFactory` to carry out its function, hence the reason I inspect this "mainInterceptor" and set the `BeanFactory` appropriately, [here](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/ProgrammaticCachingWithSpringIntegrationTests.java#L173-L175).

Another approach, which I recommend, is to use `TestConfigurationTwo`.

In this configuration, I am [configuring](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/ProgrammaticCachingWithSpringIntegrationTests.java#L185-L194) the *Spring* AOP Advice (i.e. the `CacheInterceptor`) directly, returning it from the `@Bean` definition method, "cacheInterceptor", which allows the *Spring* container to invoked the lifecycle callbacks, appropriately.

Then, I go onto [use this Advice](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/ProgrammaticCachingWithSpringIntegrationTests.java#L201) in the [cache proxy creation](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/ProgrammaticCachingWithSpringIntegrationTests.java#L196-L207) of the 3rd party class (i.e. "`Greeter`").

You should be careful to pass in the bean created from the "`cacheInterceptor`" bean definition to the "`greeter`" bean definition, [like so](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/ProgrammaticCachingWithSpringIntegrationTests.java#L197).  If you were to invoke the "`cacheInterceptor`" bean definition method from within your bean "`greeter`" bean definition, like so many users **inappropriately** do ([for example](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/ProgrammaticCachingWithSpringIntegrationTests.java#L202)), then you would forgo the *Spring* container lifecycle callbacks!  Don't do this!  The reasons for this are explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies).

Also, to read more information on the programmatic creation of proxies, you should read [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-prog).

Ok, that about covers it.

The test class I provided (i.e. "[`ProgrammaticCachingWithSpringIntegrationTests`](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/ProgrammaticCachingWithSpringIntegrationTests.java)").  Feel free to play around with it and let me know if you have any follow-up questions.

Hope this helps!

Cheers!

Comment: Peter- I believe this is core Spring Framework bug so I filed SPR-16295 - https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16295 (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16295) and submitted PR #1624 (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/1624) to resolve this issue.  For now, the workaround or the alternative approach (recommended) are sufficient to get you running.

Comment: Took me a while to get back to this. Very happy with the alternative approach. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create an `Adapter`/`Wrapper` class that delegates to the underlying 3rd party class type that you want to enable with caching.  Then, add  caching behavior to your application `Adapter`/`Wrapper` type instead.

That would be far easier to do than trying to determine the appropriate AOP Pointcut to intercept the method on the 3rd party class in which you want to advise with caching.  Of course, this approach won't work if you do not have a reference to a the object in which you want to introduce caching, in which case you will have to resort to AOP.

From your example, I get the impression that you may have a reference to this 3rd party object instance???

If not, please clarify and then I can help you with the AOP.

Comment: I considered writing a wrapper and using annotations on the method calls on it, but I thought it might be cleaner to do things without creating an extra class that proxies each method call. How far off am I with my current attempt? If it's an unreasonable amount of work to get it working I'll switch to using a wrapper.

Comment: Hi Peter- I am currently at SpringOne and will followup and give this more/proper attention after I deliver my talks.

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time